# Properly escaping strings in raw Django SQL query

Tags: sql, django, orm

Really the root of the problem is poor database design going back to long before I started here, but that problem isn't going to be resolved by the end of the day or even the end of the week. Thus, I need to find a better way to handle the following to get a feature added.

I'm forced to deviate away from the Django ORM because I need to build a raw SQL query due to having to write logic around the `FROM <table>`. We've elected to go this route instead of updating the `models.py` a couple times a year with the new tables that are added.

There are numerous areas starting [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) where the Django documentation says "Do not use string formatting on raw queries or quote placeholders in your SQL strings!"

If I write the query like this:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * \
    FROM agg_data_%s \
    WHERE dataview = %s \
    ORDER BY sortorder """, [tbl, data_view])
```

It adds single quotes around `tbl`, which obviously causes an issue, but will correctly construct the `WHERE` clause surrounded in single quotes.

Doing this, will not put single quotes around `tbl`, but will force you to put single quotes around the `WHERE` which is bad to say the least (opens it up for SQL injection):

```
sql = """ \
    SELECT * \
    FROM agg_data_%s \
    WHERE dataview = '%s' \
    ORDER BY sortorder """ % (tbl, data_view)

cursor.execute(sql)
```

Anyway to make lemonade out of these lemons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters `%s` can only be used for values. Not for (parts) of identifiers, like table/column names. If you are sure `tbl` is *safe*, then you can escape with:

```
sql = """
    SELECT * \
    FROM agg_data_%s \
    WHERE dataview = %%s \
    ORDER BY sortorder """ % tbl, [data_view])
```

Here the `%%` will "fold" to `%` and thus you yield `%s` after the first string interpolation.

But it might be better not to use different tables for this, and thus filter the table, for example by a foreign key.